# Is filter_var sufficient to sanitise integer input for PHP-based MySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I've never liked wrapping the

```
mysql_real_escape_string
```

function around input I expect to be integer for inclusion in a MySQL query.
Recently I came across the

```
filter_var
```

function. Nice!

I'm currently using the code:

```
if (isset($idUserIN) 
    && filter_var($idUserIN, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) 
    && 0 < filter_var($idUserIN, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
    ) {
      $idUser = filter_var($idUserIN, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE idUser = '.$idUser;
} else {
  // handle invalid data
}
```

Does this leave any holes open?

('> 0' chosen rather than '>= 0' as its a table auto_increment field, so 0 would not be a normal value)

Answer (score 2):

I myself would create a function for that task, possibly in a static class somewhere,

```
public static function escape_int($i) {
    $sanitised = intval($i); 
    if( '_' . $sanitised . '_' === '_' . $i . '_'  && $sanitised > 0 ) {
        return $sanitised;
    }
    throw new IntegerEscapeException( $i, $sanitised );
    return "ENOINT"; # Wont Run This, but I prepare for the impossible. 
}

try { 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE idUser = ' . DB::escape_int( $userid ); 
    DB::query($sql); 
    ...etc...
} catch( IntegerEscapeException $e ) { 
    die ( "You shot the sherif!" ); # bad example.
}
```

This is good because if I discover my sanitation method reeks I can fix it later.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler and easier-to-read method that I use is this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE idUser = ' . intval($idUser);
```

It attempts to convert $idUser to an integer and on failure returns 0 which none of my tables have as real id's. (So I know the input was invalid if it evaluates to 0.)

To answer your actual question, no that won't leave any holes open. I suggest getting rid of the repetitive code though:

```
$idUserIN_filtered = filter_var($idUserIN, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if (isset($idUserIN) 
    && $idUserIN_filtered 
    && 0 < $idUserIN_filtered
    ) {
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE idUser = '.$idUser_filtered;
} else {
  // handle invalid data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need

```
if ($idUser = filter_var($idUserIN, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE idUser = '.$idUser;
} else {
  // handle invalid data
}
```

or

```
if ($idUser = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userId', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
```

Alternatively you can check if its invalid in MVC.

```
if (!$idUser = filter_var($idUserIN, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
      throw new InputParameterException('UserId');
}
//else its valid
```